# Angularjs Checkbox checked

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

We have listing the products with the compare feature ( in checkbox). while go to next page, checkbox is unchecked. we try the following code, but we cant fix the issues.

In the View Page

```
<div class="compare-opt">Compare &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id='compare_{{inventorys.id}}'  ng-click="CompareVehicleList(inventorys.id,'List')" ng-checked="CompareCheck(inventorys.id)"></div>
```

In the Angularjs controller

```
$scope.CompareCheck=function(current_id){
  var cmp_list = $cookieStore.get("CompareList").split(",");
  if(cmp_list.length>0){
    angular.forEach(cmp_list, function(item) {
      if(parseInt(item) === parseInt(current_id)){        
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    });
  }else{
    return false;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got the solution,

```
$scope.CompareCheck=function(current_id){

  var cmp_list = $cookieStore.get("CompareList").split(",");
  if(cmp_list.length>0){
   for(j=0; j<cmp_list.length;j++){
       if(parseInt(cmp_list[j]) == parseInt(current_id)){  
          return true;
        }
   }

  }else{
    return false;
  }
```

}